# awk field separator using ":" and ignore spaces within ":"

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sh

I'm trying to automate the user creation(Bulk Users) in Linux. So, I've created a text file with all the needed parameters for user's creation.

The Text file contains the below content:

```
tom:tom1:588:0:test user1:/home/test:/bin/false
harry:harry1:589:0:test test2:/hom/test2:/bin/nologin
```

Trying to use awk command to print the column's in for loop and create the users with the information's from **/tmp/user.txt**

```
for userdetails in $(cat /tmp/user.txt) 
do
user=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $1}'`
passwd=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $2}'`
uid=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $3}'`
gid=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $4}'`
comment=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $5}'`
home_dir=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $6}'`
user_shell=`echo $userdetails | awk -v FS=: '{print $7}'`
useradd -d "$home_dir" -c "$comment" -s "$user_shell" -u "$uid" -g "$gid" "$user"
echo "$passwd" | passwd "$user" --stdin;
done
```

**Actual Output:**

```
useradd: invalid home directory ''
passwd: Unknown user name 'tom'.
useradd: invalid home directory ''
passwd: Unknown user name 'user1'.
useradd: invalid home directory ''
passwd: Unknown user name 'harry'.
useradd: invalid home directory ''
passwd: Unknown user name 'test2'.
```

What I'm doing wrong ?

P.S : I am aware there is a command called newusers  in Linux, but i need to check the same via script to create bulk users in Linux.

Comment: seems like you need `sed 's/:/-/g' /tmp/user.txt` or `awk -v FS=":" -v OFS="-" '{$1=$1}1'`

Comment: [Don't read lines with for](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor) and as @PS. has mentioned this can be done in a single line using a tool such as sed or awk.

Comment: edited the entire question with the real purpose of the script.

Comment: What's tripping you up is that the `for` loop is using white space to delimit the output of `cat`.  That is, the whitespace in your comment field is causing your loop to execute four times where you seem to be expecting it to execute twice, using only the newline as the delimiter.  You can work around that with `IFS`, but I bet you'll get some better ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use while for read a file by line so the entire line will be stored in the variable you choose( in my case: line) . Then you could echo variable and awk will do the rest of the work. I prefer $() than `` so I use both for now. For this much data you could create a loop into the while to make code sorter and better manageable.

```
cat /tmp/user.txt | while read line
do
user=`echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'`
passwd=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $2}')
uid=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $3}')
gid=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $4}')
comment=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $5}')
home_dir=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $6}')
user_shell=$(echo $line | awk -F ":" '{print $7}')

useradd -d "$home_dir" -c "$comment" -s "$user_shell" -u "$uid" -g "$gid" "$user"

echo "$passwd" | passwd "$user" --stdin;

done
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :)

Comment: What is the point of using awk above? Also, in addition to a UUOC plus being inefficient and non-portable there are several ways that script could fail due to not following fundamental shell quoting rules.

Comment: @EdMorton Yes you right, your answer for the task is more effective, yet the OP were like to know whats wrong with his awk command too. I decided to make a code like his, so he able to find out what he may missed.

Comment: Your awk commands do exactly the same as the OPs do. The "fix" in your answer is to use a while read loop instead of a for loop but then you shouldn't use cat, you should set IFS, you should add -r for read, you shouldn't use awk, and you should quote your variables so overall YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

idk how you got started on that track but you're off-base. Just use a shell loop:

```
while IFS=':' read -r user passwd uid gid comment home_dir user_shell; do
    useradd -d "$home_dir" -c "$comment" -s "$user_shell" -u "$uid" -g "$gid" "$user"
    echo "$passwd" | passwd "$user" --stdin;
done < /tmp/user.txt
```

The above is just showing how to read the file contents into variables, it assumes you know what you're doing with the "useradd" and "passwd" lines.

Answer (score 0):

If you are stuck with awk, you can use  [Awk Global substitution](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/awk-one-liners-explained-part-two/):

```
awk '{gsub(/:/,"-")} 1' your_file
```

This is also feasible using [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) with the `g` flag ( [Sed Global substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#index-Global-substitution) ):

```
sed "s/:/-/g" your_file
```

In both casesn your edited lines would be printed to the screen.